# Converting HTML Text to Markdown

Tags: android, github-flavored-markdown, multimarkdown

I have an html Text which we get from rich text editor and where I need to convert that rich text to markdown text

for ex :

rich text  return

```
<b> strong </b>
    to 
**strong**
```

Can any one help me in Android

Answer (score 0):

**you can also load from an HTML string:**

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

**(or)**

**For example (< Android Nougat):**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

**For example (>= Android Nougat):**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

> My suggestion is better to use **webview**.because table tags and some
>   more tags are not showing in **Textview**... [Webview doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [XSLT](http://www.lowerelement.com/Geekery/XML/XHTML-to-Markdown.html) for converting html to markdown in java android.
here is the example to use in Android.

```
 void test(String theHTML)
{
    File xsltFile = new File("mardownXSLT.xslt");

    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(theHTML));
    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);

    TransformerFactory transFact =
            TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    trans.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(result));
}
```

Comment: @Anbu `result.toString()` is the Converted String

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [remark](https://remark.overzealous.com/) library (the download on the page is broken but it's also available on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.overzealous/remark)) which also supports GitHub and Multimarkdown flavored markdown. The code could look as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String html = "<b>Foo</b>";
    final Remark remark = new com.overzealous.remark.Remark(com.overzealous.remark.Options.github()); // or Options.markdown() or Options.multiMarkdown()
    remark.setCleanedHtmlEchoed(false);
    System.out.println(remark.convert(html));
}
```

Output: `**Foo**`

Answer (score -1):

**Try this code**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String htmlText = "<b> strong </b>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText).toString());
```

Comment: Please Read the above question  and Answer I was asking the html text to markdown not  to render it.